# email body is not showing up (swift mailer PHP)

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm using swift mailer to send email verification via 'gmail', but the problem is I receive a blank email without body,
[Here is what I get in my email :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK7MN.png) 
Here is my code :

```
<?php 
  require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
  require_once './config/constants.php';

  // Create the Transport
  $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.googlemail.com', 465, 'ssl'))
      ->setUsername(EMAIL)
      ->setPassword(PASSWORD)
    ;
  
  // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
  $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
  
  
  function sendEmailVerification($userEmail, $userToken){
    global $mailer;
    $body = `
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <p>
            Thank you for Signing in to ESP. Please click on the link below to Verify your Account.
          </p>
          <a href="http://localhost/eps/login.php?token='. $userToken .'">Verify your Acount</a>
        </div>
      </body>
      </html>
    `;
    // Create a message
      $message = (new Swift_Message('Verify Your email'))
        ->setFrom( EMAIL )
        ->setTo($userEmail)
        ->setBody($body)
        ->setContentType('text/html')
        ;
      
      // Send the message
      $mailer->send($message); //tried also $result = $mailer->send($message);
  }
?>
```

Any Solution Please !

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I have just removed the back ticks and replaced it with simple quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change backtick(`) to single quote('):

```
 $body = '
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <p>
            Thank you for Signing in to ESP. Please click on the link below to Verify your Account.
          </p>
          <a href="http://localhost/eps/login.php?token='. $userToken .'">Verify your Acount</a>
        </div>
      </body>
      </html>
    ';
```

This concept is more of variable interpolation.

Where strings can be enclosed within single quotes or double quotes.

If we have to add double quote around any element in a string, we can start that string with single quote and vice versa.

Please look into following syntaxes, all 3 are correct:

```
echo '<div class="myCls" id="myId">Some Content Here</div>';
```

AND

```
echo "<div class='myCls' id='myId'>Some Content Here</div>";
```

AND

```
echo "<div class=\"myCls\" id=\"myId\">Some Content Here</div>"; 
// Escaping the characters with '\' character.
```

At least for me, I prefer the first one.